# Spring Slice Specification Pagable

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to use Slice with Specification and Pagable; not List or Page.
The following is working in a JpaRepository:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, UUID>,
    JpaSpecificationExecutor<Person> {

    Slice<Person> findAllBy(Pageable pageable);
}
```

But if i add a Specification at least 1 parameter is provided and it will be failed:

```
Slice<Person> findAllBy(Specification<Person> specification, Pageable pageable);
```

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least 1 parameter(s) provided but only 0 parameter(s) present in query.
```

Comment: Does your repository implements `JpaSpecificationExecutor`?

Comment: Yes. I update the question.

Comment: Nice, can you add the error you're getting as well?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least 1 parameter(s) provided but only 0 parameter(s) present in query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not supported by Spring Data JPA. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/1311

You'd have to create a custom method to achieve this.